# Initate RSync From Webpage

Tags: rsync

I use rsync for backups. I'd like a script that when someone visits a certain url *(It will be private and internal only)* that it will start a rsync job on demand straight away.

Could someone advise me how I could do this?

Comment: Hmm, there's some detail missing here. Why do you want the backups to work this way?

Comment: Basically, i want to use it so one of my web developers can push a file from a development server to a web production server.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to move code from development into production?

Comment: Yep, basically. - At the moment rsync does it a 4:30am daily. I am looking for something that if a urgent push is needed a script can be initiated from a webpage or something likewise. I presumed rsync would be the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rsync? Sure, that will get the job done. But it's like using a hammer to drive in screws.

If you're pushing code, use a proper repository tool. There are plenty out there, and if the code isn't compiled, a Git client on the box or a post-commit hook would work fine.

Remember, don't simply solve today's problem, make sure your solution is scalable enough to solve tomorrow's, even if you're not quite there yet.

Comment: I agree your answer whole-heartedly, but you may want to police the tone of your first sentence; it reads a little dismissively. All that said, you gave great recommendations.

Comment: Thank you for your input, DTK. The analogy is *very* apt as the use of remotely-triggered rsync for a production code deployment system simply does not scale. If you're particularly unhappy with the tone, you are free to flag it.

Comment: I agree that it is not a solution that will scale, and will likely cause a huge rework in the future. I don't think the tone was flag-worthy, and I appreciate your pointing him in the right direction to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync is often not be the best tool to facilitate promoting code from development into production.

If your developers are shipping compiled code, they would benefit from a workflow to build-test-package-deploy, and you can empower them by setting up a repository and a workflow engine to do this.

If they are simply pushing scripts, they can probably use the facilities of their source-code versioning tool (like GIT) to move the work-product into production, although they would gain benefit from a tooling infrastructure described above.

Take a look at Hudson[1] or Jenkins[2], both of which are workflow engines specifically designed for "continuous (quality|integration|deployment)". A more general-purpose workflow engine like jBPM from Red Hat[3] would also do the job very well.

While these tools add some up-front setup, they enable your developers to implement a Continuous Quality[4], Continuous Integration[5] and Continuous Deployment[6] discipline, all of which will catch problems early and reduce the chances you will get a late night call to roll-back a code because a hard-to-spot defect crept in.

While you are at it, look at packaging their full work-product (code, module, script, etc) into a package (CPAN if it is perl, NPM if it is NodeJS, RPM if the production servers run Red Hat, CentOS or Oracle Unbreakable) and place it into a repository, so that the full work-product can be delivered atomically, versioned, and if necessary rolled-back.

While your OS probably provides a tool for maintaining a repository (create-repo for Red Hat and friends), you may get additional lift by leveraging powerful repo management softwares, such as JFrog Artifactory[7] or Sonatype Nexus[8], since they provide robust management capabilities, web-based repo management and other capabilities.

[1]: See http://hudson-ci.org "Hudson"
  [2]: See http://jenkins-ci.org "Jenkins"
  [3]: See http://jbpm.org "jBPM"
  [4]: Run a battery of tests against every commit, and blow the commit if a mistake is found, so mistakes are less likely to sneak into production
  [5]: Test that your newly updated code will play nicely with the rest of your environment before it goes live
  [6]: Promote codes to production as soon as they are production-ready, enabling incremental changes
  [7]: See http://jfrog.com/open-source/ "Artifactory"
  [8]: See http://www.sonatype.org/nexus "Sonatype Nexus"

Comment: Please do keep in mind that specific products references and link lists go out of date. Products come and go, and these links will go dead over time. Which is one of the reasons that product-heavy questions are frowned upon here.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that; I will keep that in-mind. In my zeal to provide actionable guidance, I may have made it to specific and may have made it appear to too heavily rely on specific tools, rather than the mindset the tools drive. I appreciate the pointer and why this can be a pit-fall.